# Cannot get current URL in php function get_meta_tags

Tags: php

I have a little problem with get_meta_tags.
I want to include it on several sites, so it must take meta from current site.

```
$current_site = $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"] . $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$tags = get_meta_tags($current_site);
```

Tried to do this that way (when I echo $current_site i get the proper address), byt can't get metatags when using it :(

Comment: You get any actual errors? Also, are these being hosted on Apache/NGINX or IIS?

Comment: Also, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6768793/get-the-full-url-in-php is a better way to set the site url. Granted, it only works for http and not https, but there are plenty of other examples for that.

Comment: It's Apache server. I don't see any errors on the top of page - should I check them in any other way? I'm not php specialist at all ^^
My site is ran over fully https :(

Comment: Make a test page that just echos the `$current_site` variable. I think you'll need to add `https://` to the front of it if your site is 100% https

Comment: Heu JClaspill, post answer with adding https:// so I can mark it :) it works now, didn't think that would matter! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Glad to help. Amazing how it is usually the little things that fix it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your site is all https, you should add `https://` to the front of your variable.

```
$current_site = 'https://'.$_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
$tags = get_meta_tags($current_site);
```